# URL decode unicode characters (%EF%AC%81 need "fi" as two letters not unicode symbol)

Tags: unicode, character, ascii, uri, decode

I am using the `decodeURIComponent()` function on a string containing the following:

```
"%EF%AC%81"
```

Which gives me `"fi"` when decoded, which is what I want.  But (please forgive incorrect terminology, I'm not sure about this stuff), it doesn't seem to give the characters in the correct coding. As the resulting string is then used with a regex to remove anything that isn't alphanumerical, the `"fi"` is also getting removed. I have tried just passing the phrase `"find?"` to my regex, and it returns `"find"`, so it should work.

Is there a way to convert the `%EF%AC%81` to regular characters, i.e. `"f"` and `"i"` rather than the `"fi"`, which [according to this](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=64256&number=128) seems to be "latin small ligature fi".

Comment: `"ﬁ".normalize("NFKD")` would decompose to `"fi"` but no support in IE

Comment: `EF AC 81` is the UTF-8 encoded form of the `ﬁ` (U+FB01 LATIN SMALL LIGATURE FI) character, which is a single character, not the two characters `f` and `i` that you are looking for.  Like Alex said, you would have to [decompose the string](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/) to get what you are looking for.

Comment: tried Alex's answer yesterday and it worked perfectly. How do i mark that as the answer and this question as solved ?

Answer (score 0):

Alex' comment is the answer, i used the `.normalize("NFKD")` function and got "fi" as two characters.